# How to achieve a similar effect (rocks)?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to figure out how to acheve the effect of the rocks (in the back).

I've started by taking a plane, subdividing, and then moving vertices s

[image: s)]

Comment: Yep, that's how I would approach it. You could also do it from a Displacement Modifier/Texture and control the height from an image.

Comment: I can displace using a texture ? Wow !
Height from an image ? can you please explain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way:

- Create a plane, subdivide, play with the *Fractal* value in the *Operator* box, flatten it on the Z axis.

[image]

- Extrude to create the cliff, extrude again to create a cliff on the cliff, create some horizontal edge loops:

[image]

- Enable the *Proportional Editing* option and move some vertices. Don't give any *Subsurf* modifier or *Smooth Shading* to keep a low-poly look:

[image]

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly the look i was aiming for ! Also, learned about the Fractal modifier ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Hey, BTW, if you have weird shading issues, turn on smooth shading, and add a **edge split modifier** with the angle set to zero.  this is a good rule of thumb for low poly style renders, as it keeps the mesh from having dark lines across the faces.

Comment: actually I think he does want the triangulation effect  ;)